# How to order DESC and display horizontally PHP

Tags: php, sql

I was wondering how I would order something DESC but then make all the results display horizontally instead of vertically.

```
$sql = "SELECT name WHERE id > 5 ORDER BY id DESC";
```

Comment: How do you display is by your programming language, in your example, PHP. Have you ever tried ?

Comment: What do you mean by horizontally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put all the names in a comma-separated list, using `group_concat()`:

```
select group_concat(name order by id) as names
from t
where id > 5
```

You can then break out each name from the list.  (And, if the comma is not the right separator, you can use the `separator` keyword.)